# Ionic 3 how to show data from array in row and column?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have data in array. I need to show in 2 row and column . 
in data their is 4 array. But sometimes it will be 3 or 2 . So I need to design like as attach.

[image]

```html
<ion-list *ngFor="let f of f1"> {{f.name}} {{f.age}}</ion-list>
```

This is how I'm showing in list but need to show as attach.

Answer (score 0):

Put in the CSS file:

```
ion-list.twocolumns {
  display: inline-block;
}

ion-list.twocolumns ion-item {
  float: left;
  list-style: outside none none;
  width: 50%;
}
```

And changue your HTML like this:

```
<ion-list class="twocolumns">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let f of f1"> {{f.name}} {{f.age}} </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

This should display the elements in two colums